# I am getting compiler errors while compiling my code in unix

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, compiler-errors

i have two folders named Source and powerserver in my home directory. In source direectory i have some code related to project and it uses a .h header file from power server directory. when am compiling using `make -f somename.lnx32` I am getting the below error.

```
error: cst.h no such file or directory.
```

I am new to this i dont know how to access that .h file ?

Comment: So, is that the name of the file you're knowingly including?

Comment: you should provide your code.

Comment: yes. we are knowlingly including

Comment: #include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <cst.h>

#include <dllapi.h> I am using all these .h files in my .c file

Comment: You should probably rather show what's in your makefile. Edit that into your question please.

Comment: PROGRAM= $(LIB)/libdllapi.a
CC= gcc
DFLAGS = -g 
CFLAGS = $(DFLAGS)
IFLAGS= -I. -I../include -I$(CSTPINC) 
COMPILE = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(IFLAGS) -c
LINK.c  = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS)
CSTPINC =../extern/cstplus.533/include
DFLAGS = -g -DSVR4 -m32
CFLAGS  = $(DFLAGS)
LIB  = ../lib.lnx32
OBJ  = ../obj.lnx32
OBJECTS = $(OBJ)/dllapi.o
$(PROGRAM): $(OBJECTS)
 ar r $(PROGRAM) $(OBJ)/dllapi.o
 @echo "DLL API Linux Library Updated......."
 ../extern/what.100/bin.lnx/what $(PROGRAM) | grep VPROC
$(OBJ)/dllapi.o: dllapi.c
$(COMPILE) dllapi.c -o $(OBJ)/dllapi.o
clean:
rm -f $(OBJ)/dllapi.o
rm -f /$(PROGRAM)

Comment: @sandeep: If you have information to add to your question then use the EDIT function. Nobody wants to read ugly unformatted code or make files in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

GCC looks in several different places for headers. On a normal Unix system, if you do not instruct it otherwise, it will search in default directories.

You can add directories to this list with the -I command-line option. All the directories named by -I are searched, in left-to-right order, before the default directories.

Try `gcc -c -I/path_to_powerserver_directory` to include header files in GCC search path.

Currently this particular header file is not found to gcc in it's search paths.

Comment: In particular, `<cst.h>` & `<dllapi.h>` (mentioned in comments) are usually not available on Linux (as system provided header files).

Comment: sorry for troubling you guys.. corrected the folder structure it started compiling without any errors.. thanks everyone for spending your valuable time. many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's tagged Linux so i guess you use GCC.

`#include <someheader.h>` means to search someheader.h in system directories (ie. /usr/include), which you can override using the -Ipath option with GCC.

But in your case, you should be using `#include "someheader.h"` with the correct user path in your Makefile with the -iquote option.